# embdedding flv and xml

Tags: php, xml, flv

i am working on a project where i am trying to embed a flv file and it's corresponding xml file(this has some info regarding the flv movie). I would like to know if there is any player that i can use to embed this with xml. 
I will be creating a page and that will list all these videos like
1) video1  dec 25 2010
2) video 2 jan 1st 2011
clicking on the "video1" should either open a new page and play the video there and show the xml file contents too. Or like how 5min.com plays the video just in the popup...can any one please let me know if there is any tutorial on embedding these flv's? flash is new to me but i can do php part of it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't directly embed a flv from XML file. But you can parse XML with PHP and then embed.

You can use PHP's [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) class
Example :

```
<?php
$obj = simplexml_load_file(XML_FILE);
/* There is an example XML file
<video>
   <one>
      <flv>FLV URL 1</flv>
    </one>
</video> */
echo $obj->video->one->flv;
?>
```

Comment: hi, i have flv and xml files..i already have it separately..i just want to know how to play this flv when a video is clicked

Comment: i couldn't understood. Which web player, do you using?

Comment: i am not using anything, that' the question..how i am supposed to embed this flv file into a player so that it's played in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I did by using php file handling and JW player. I called the files from the folder and clicking on each thumbnail played the video in next page using JW player. thanks for all the help.